# what is the _correct_ way to write "a or b" kind of type hints in docstring?

Tags: python, typing, python-typing, docstring

I have an argument which is either "E" or "H".

```
def my_func(name):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    name : str
    """
```

To specify it's either 'E' or 'H' I've seen people writing:

```
    name : {'E', 'H'}
```

```
    name : ['E', 'H']
```

```
    name : ['E' | 'H']
```

```
    name : Union['E', 'H']
```

```
    name : 'E' or 'H'
```

Or, putting those on the second line:

```
    name : str
        {'E', 'H'}
```

```
    name : str
        ['E', 'H']
```

```
    name : str
        ['E' | 'H']
```

```
    name : str
        Union['E', 'H']
```

```
    name : str
        'E' or 'H'
```

which one of the above is **correct**?

If it's `int` or `float`, which one of the following is correct?

```
  param : int or float
```

```
  param : Union[int, float]
```

```
  param : [int | float]
```

```
  param : {int, float}
```

Comment: alternatively, you can just type hint in function definition, no need to duplicate it in docstring

Comment: `def my_func(name: typing.Literal['E', 'H']):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any *correct* way IMHO, but as I can see that [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) uses a lot of these ways.

For [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply), there are:

```
axis : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0
```

---

```
result_type : {‘expand’, ‘reduce’, ‘broadcast’, None}, default None
```

And for [`pd.DataFrame.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html#pandas.DataFrame.aggregate):

```
func : function, str, list or dict
```

---

And for a [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) array, [`np.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy-array) has:

```
order : {‘K’, ‘A’, ‘C’, ‘F’}, optional
```

And for [`np.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) you got:

```
shape : int or tuple of ints
```

And `typing.Union` is also surely often used.

All of these are considerably *correct*, these ones [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) and [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) uses are considered more *common*.

Answer (score 1):

I would allways use the Union class from typehint like this:

```py
from typing import Union

def my_func(name: Union[a, b]):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    name : a | b
    """
    pass

´´´
```

Comment: see my "cheat sheet" above; using typing there's no confusion. The confusion is about the type hints in docstring.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here is a `cheat sheet` of the "`a` or `b`" type hints in *docstring* that are **correctly recognized** by pycharm to check inconsistencies when you pass arguments:

```
name : str or dict
name : str, dict
name : str | dict
name : {str or dict}
name : {str, dict}
name : {str | dict}
```

```
name : 'E', 123   # recognized as str or int
name : {'E', 123}  # recognized as str or int
```

```
name : list[float or dict]
name : list[float, dict]  # this will be understood as a list of a float and a dict, not as List[Union[float, dict]]
name : list[float | dict]
```

The following **can't be processed correctly** by pycharm:

```
name : [str or dict]
name : [str, dict]
name : [str | dict]
name : Union[str, dict]
```

```
name : 'E' or 123
name : 'E' | 123
name : {'E' or 123}
name : {'E' | 123}
name : ['E' or 123]
name : ['E', 123]  # recognized as int
name : ['E' | 123]
```

```
list{float or dict}
list{float, dict}  # recognized as dict
list{float | dict}
list of ***  # No matter what you put here, e.g. list of {int, float}, it won't be corrected processed.#

# none of the expressions I can come up with can express "list of elements that are either 123 or 'abc'".
```